# How to load your image dataset in python

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I have a folder (on my windows desktop) containing the images I want to use to build my deep learning classifier. I also have one .csv file which has the image number (for example img_1035) and the corresponding class label. **How do I load the dataset with the labels into python/jupyter notebooks?**
This is the link to the dataset on kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/debdoot/bdrw).

I would preferably like to use **PyTorch** to do this but any other ways would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: you should look at how to build a custom _Dataset_ in pytorch. should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, PyTorch has a convenient ["ImageFolder" class](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder) that you can extend to create your own dataset.

Here's an example of a dataset that uses ImageFolder:

```
class MyDataset(torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder):

def __init__(self, train_folder_path='.', transform=None, target_transform=None):
    super().__init__(train_folder_path, transform, target_transform)

# [ Some functions omitted ]
```

Then you load your set using PyTorch's "DataLoader". 
Here's an example for a training set:

```
training_set = MyDataset(root_path, transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

Using the train loader you can get batches from your dataset. You can then use these batches to train / validate and so on:

```
batch = next(iter(train_loader))
images, labels = batch
```

Training is a rather involved process so I'm not entirely sure how deep you want to dive here. I hope this was a nudge in the right direction.